# Problem with sorting of bibliography with biblatex-chicago in Sharelatex

Tags: bibliographies, sharelatex, biblatex-chicago

I am having a bit of a problem with a paper I am working on in Sharelatex. For some reason I can not get the bibliography to sort alphabetically.

The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,sorting=nyt,cmsdate=both,maxcitenames=3]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

Text \nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And my bib-file looks like this:

```
@book{almqvist1984,
author={Solveig Almqvist},
title={Geng{\aa}ngarf{\"o}rest{\"a}llningar i svensk folktro ur genreanalytisk synpunkt},
publisher={Almqvist {\&} Wiksell international},
address={Stockholm},
year={1984},
titleaddon={(\bibstring{phdthesis})},
} 

@book{hall2013,
author={Mikael Häll},
title={Skogsrået, näcken och Djävulen: Erotiska naturväsen och demonisk sexualitet i 1600- och 1700-talens Sverige},
year={2013},
publisher={Malört},
address={Stockholm},
titleaddon={(\bibstring{phdthesis})},
}

@book{stattin1984,
author={Jochum Stattin},
title={Näcken: spelman eller gränsvakt?},
year={1992},
origdate={1984},
publisher={Carlsson},
address={Stockholm},
titleaddon={(\bibstring{phdthesis})},
}

@book{worsley1968,
author={Peter Worsley},
title={The trumpet shall sound: A study of ”cargo” cults in Melanesia},
year={1968},
publisher={Schocken Books},
address={New York},
}
```

For some reason the output I get sorts the bibliography in way that puts Worsley 1968 first in the list:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong. Indeed, I cannot reproduce the issue, for the entries are sorted as expected for me (with an up to date TeX Live 2018). Could you please tell us which version of `biblatex` you are running? You should be able to find it in your log file. (I won't be able to do much with it, but the information will likely be useful to the more knowledgeable).

Comment: Ah, this probably might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361282/105447.

Comment: It seems to be this version "Package: biblatex-chicago 2017/04/19 v 3.7 biblatex style" and "biblatex 2016/12/05 v3.7 "

Comment: Also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396126/35864

Answer (score 0):

It does seem, as *gusbrs* indicated, to be the bug/problem hinted at here: [Can't sort references alphabetically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361282/cant-sort-references-alphabetically)

This:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,authordate,sorting=nyt,cmsdate=both,maxcitenames=3]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

Text \nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Now results in:
[image]

Comment: Did the link solve the problem to you? If so, I think it is best if we mark this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Yes it dit. I do not think I am able to mark that myself though.

Comment: I can do so. But I think your change to the `bibtex` as a "solution" is less than ideal. `bibtex` is regarded as a legacy backend for `biblatex` which does not have the full functionality granted by `biber`. I'd suggest you that ideally work with an up to date installation (this issue is clearly dealt with for the current version) or, if that's not possible, use moewe's answer.

Comment: Ok! I was not sure on how to update my version of biblatex since I am running it through ShareLatex.

Comment: Indeed you don't have that option within ShareLaTeX. I would have to go for a local installation.

Comment: You can try the option `sortlocale=en` to override the broken Swedish sorting temporarily. But then your document follows English sorting rules and not Swedish rules. With `backend=bibtex` you can't sort Unicode characters properly either, so both options fare equally bad in that regard.

Comment: @moewe I tired that now as well, but the English sorting rules adds some extra problems with sorting names properly that has å, ä, and ö in them. I think I will go with your `sortname={{}}` tweak  from [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396126/sort-aa-as-an-%c3%a5-using-biber] will be my best choice as of now.